# (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON

Tags: json

I converted a JSONObject to String by using

```
String a = b.toString();
```

and then convert it back using

```
JSONObject c = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(a);
```

it throws a JSON string not valid exception but the JSONObject is actually created successfully and all the info can be parsed correctly. Just so weird...Anybody knows why?

Thanks

Comment: what value does `a` have?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the object directly to the serializer, you should not need to convert it to a string in the middle:

```
JSONObject c = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(b);
```

Comment: Hi, I will have to. Sorry for confusing you. I will have to store the json string and then convert it back later. Thanks.